# .NET: Correctly implement DataSourceAttribute for local .mdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am trying to create some data-driven unit tests in my C# solution. My data is in a file `TestData.mdf`. On my test method, I'm using the `DataSourceAttribute` to specify where to pull the data for testing. The test data should be coming from a table `String_CanParseBooleanData` in the `TestData.mdf` database file.

I have tried using all the constructors for `DataSourceAttribute`, with numerous different connection strings and provider invariant names, and cannot get past connection errors on the test.

The test method is just a skeleton so far, so I don't think it is the cause of any issue:

```
[TestMethod]
public void String_CanParseBoolean() {
    Assert.Inconclusive();
}
```

If I add a connection to my MDF file in the Server Explorer window, it lists the provider as

```
.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server
```

This does not look anything like the values for provider name invariant I've seen in code examples or Microsoft documentation. Those provider names are `System.Data.SqlClient` or `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0`, and if I use this for the provider element of the connection string, I will get an error that says that provider is not registered locally.  If I use that for the provider argument of the attribute, I get an error saying it cannot find the provider.

What provider do I need to use an MDF file in VS2013?

Comment: This discussion might be of use as an example to work off of. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fee09a3-2ef7-4db5-bc30-b4d288cae8d3/unit-test-problem-with-datasource-attribute?forum=vststest

Comment: From MS's guide online: [DataSource(@"Provider=Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.4.0; Data Source=C:\Data\MathsData.sdf;", "Numbers")] //(connection string, table). sub in your own stuff.

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  The question I suppose is what is "my own stuff".  That provider is not working.  SDF files are also no longer supported.  I'm not sure if that's the cause of the issue, but I can't find any documentation dealing specifically with MDF files, which seem to be their successor.